# Is HttpServlet class is an abstract class? if yes then how ?please can one explain detail

Tags: servlets

Respected to every answerers.....

Sir , i am perceiving MCA  (MASTER OF COMPUTER APPLICATIONS) pg course...
 we have gone through our syllabus, but we were not able to findout that , IS HttpServlet class is an abstract class ...or not.... in some books it has given it is an abstract class, but in another as not a abstract class...so we are in confusing.....sooo

please can any one explain us what is real.....

please give me answer.... thanks to everyone

Comment: Why don't you just look at the documentation?

Comment: You could find out by just trying to save "HttpServlet s = new HttpServlet()" and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.1/api/javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.html) says it's `abstract`.